# What parsing strategy is best for Http messages?

Tags: java, http, parsing, kotlin, adt

I'd like to create a program that parses http requests and responses. I already have created its ADT following the specification [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616), which was pretty easy given that every message follows the same structure. [ADTs in Kotlin](https://medium.com/sharenowtech/kotlin-adt-74472319962a).

I've looked into some parsing libraries like [better-parse](https://github.com/h0tk3y/better-parse) and [jparsec](https://github.com/jparsec/jparsec), but they seem overkill for what I'm trying to accomplish; and I might be wrong but I don't think that tokenizing the whole input regardless of the context is the most appropriate way of doing so.

So my questions are: Is there a different kind of parser more appropriate for my task? Do those have a name? Or should I try to implement it myself?

Comment: Do want to parse HTTP requests / responses, or the **content** of HTTP requests / responses? If the latter, what does it have to do with HTTP at all? What format is the content?

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained myself more clearly. I'm trying to make my own http server with sockets, so it has to be able to parse the whole message.